# Ruby colon hash syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby, eclipse, aptana, syntax-highlighting

I'm a pretty heavy user of colon hashes but the default Aptana Studio Ruby doesn't provide any highlighting for them.

Here's a colon hash in Ruby 1.9:

```
{ animal: "duck" }
```

Does anyone know what bits I need to punch to make the "animal:" part display in another colour?

**Update:**

It seems from reading the source that the PLists file isn't being used by Aptana and that the feature is presently incomplete.
https://github.com/textmate/ruby.tmbundle/issues/17

I've tried changing the scopes in source but it doesn't seem to update for me.

To find the scope Aptana is trying to highlight

1. *Commands* -> *Bundle Development* -> *Show Scope and Matching Theme Rule* (alternatively the default shortcut is **Ctrl+Alt+P**)
2. Read the box. It may list several scopes.

The way you add a scope:

1. *Window* -> *Preferences*
2. Select *Aptana Studio* then the *Themes* option.
3. Press the **+** button next to the *Scope Selector* textbox.
4. Add your scope and set the colours.
5. Apply and click *OK*

I'm all out of ideas. Hopefully this will help someone get closer.

Comment: If you can find the JavaScript object parser, that would be very close.

Comment: Don't you get a syntax error message? I'm having that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3 uses TextMate themes for syntax highlighting, so you just need to find a TextMate theme that supports it.

Comment: Yes, it uses TextMate themes but it doesn't highlight the key part of the hash with any of the TextMate themes I've tried so far. I think it may be a matter of adding a scope selector (like this one: https://github.com/textmate/ruby.tmbundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/Ruby.plist#L1562)

Comment: I think you are correct, it is a matter of adding a scope selector, but Aptana doesn't seem to provide any means of defining them, any new themes can only make use of pre-existing selectors.